# Possible to use Tomcat DIGEST authentication with custom form?

Tags: tomcat, digest-authentication

From what I understand I can do either:

```
<login-config>
     <auth-method>DIGEST</auth-method>
     <realm-name>...</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

or

```
<login-config>
   <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
   <realm-name>...</realm-name>
   <form-login-config>
     <form-login-page>...</form-login-page>
     <form-error-page>...</form-error-page>
   </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

My passwords are stored as SHA-256 encoded "username:realm:password" but I want to use my own login and error pages rather than the browser's built-in popup window. How do I do this?